# Get text content and write to HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a little game thing where you can enter words and such, but the main issue is that when I try to make JavaScript print out the words I write; it doesn't ever work properly!
Here is my HTML:

```
<input id="verb" name="verb" type="text" placeholder="Enter a verb">
<input id="noun" name="noun" type="text" placeholder="Enter a noun">
<button onclick="getWords()">Enter</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

And here's the JavaScript to go with it:

```
var verb = document.getElementById("verb").textContent;
var noun = document.getElementById("noun").textContent;
      function getWords()
      {
          document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You chose " +verb+ " as your verb, and " +noun+ " as your noun";
      }
```

When you click the enter button in Google Chrome; it simply says that "You chose undefined as your verb, and undefined as your noun."
Why doesn't it recognize the contents of the elements and just fill them with "undefined," no matter what is entered?  Is there an easier way to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the `verb` and `noun` accessions to the inside of your `getWords` function.

Comment: try `document.getElementById("id").val();` and  `document.getElementById("id").val("your value");` instead

Comment: @Wold - There is no JavaScript `.val()` function. Thinking of jQuery perhaps?

Comment: oh right, of course you'd need to use jQuery for that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  function getWords()
  {
      var verb = document.getElementById("verb").value;
      var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You chose " +verb+ " as your verb, and " +noun+ " as your noun";
  }
```

value holds the text in an input whereas innerHTML represents the HTML in an element. Therefore you need to read the values of the inputs and store them in the HTML of the paragraph element.

Comment: You will need to move the variable declarations into the function `getWords` (IIUC)...

Comment: i forgot to move the verb and noun declarations into the getWords scope, thanks

Comment: This is right; I used this code and moved the variable accessions  inside the function and it worked! You guys were 100% correct with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. In your html, try to use

```
    function getWords() {

    var verb = document.getElementById("verb").value;
    var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;

      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You chose " + verb + " as your verb, and " + noun + " as your noun.";
    }
```

This is the way you need to do it - the way you have written your code, the vars verb and noun are never read. by including them inside the function getWords(), you ensure that the value will only be looked at AFTER the user has clicked the button.